# Sum of iid variables converge in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be independent and identically distributed random variables. Let $A_n=\sum_{p=1}^nY_p\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If $\varphi_{Y_1}$ is differentiable in $0$, show that there exists an $z\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\frac{A_n}{n}\rightarrow z$$
in probability for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I know that in order to converge in probability the following most hold:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(|Y_n-Y|>\epsilon)=0$$

for all $\epsilon >0$. I somehow need to use the fact that $\varphi_{Y_1}$ is differentiable in $0$, but I dont know where to start.

Comment: Ideally this should be converging to $\mathbb{E}[Y]$. But how do you know that $\mathbb{E}[Y] < \infty$? Maybe you have the Cauchy distribution?

Comment: I am not given any distribution, how do you come up with the Cauchy distribution? - And do you get that it should converge to $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ because we have the Cauchy Distribution?

Comment: @gt6989b The characteristic function of the Cauchy distribution is not differentiable at 0, so this is no problem.

Comment: I've once read that for a non-negative random variable X, where $\varphi_X$ is differentiabel in $0$ implies that $x\in \mathcal{L}^1(P)$, hence $\mathbb{E}[X]<\infty$, though I dont know how to show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show $A_n/n\to z$ in probability, it suffices to show $A_n/n\to z$ in distribution (prove this!), which entails showing the characteristic function for $A_n/n$ converges to $e^{izt}$ (by Lévy's continuity theorem).

The characteristic function for $A_n/n$ is $\varphi(t/n)^n$. Now

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi(t/n)^n = \exp(\lim_{n\to\infty} \log \varphi(t/n)^n),
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log  \varphi(t/n)^n = t\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\phi(t/n)}{t/n}
$$

The last limit exists, and equals derivative of $\log \phi(t)$ at $t=0$.

Comment: How do you get the last - that the limit is equal to the derivative of $log(\phi(t))$ at $t=0$?

Comment: The derivative is $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\log\phi(h)-\log\phi(0)}{h}$$Now replace $h$ with $t/n$, and recall that $\phi(0)=1$. @FrankEpsi